# How to create template of guides in Illustrator which appears with every document I open?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

So, I am working on a multiple page pdf. I need to setup margins on each side of the page using guides. There are 300+ pages and I am working on each page at a time. I don't want to add guides in each page manually. Even coping the guides from one page to another is tedious and frustrating. Is there any way to set up the guides in way that appears every time I open a new page? If not guides is there any way to  get around this problem?

Comment: not sure if it works or not but maybe it's possible by creating script which after can be assigned as hotkey so once you'll open page just press that hotkey and guides should added automatically!

Comment: This sounds like a job for Indesign no question about it. You can make a master page with the guides and then just apply that master to all pages you need. Master pages can be nested too. You can also have different column settings for each master page: `Layout > Margins and Columns...` → if you add columns this way, you can easily align and flow text in these columns.

Comment: Illustrator has an **artboard limit** of 100 artboards. Illustrator is the *wrong tool* for what you are trying to do, it's not designed for "book", "catalog", or "manual" creation. Use InDesign.

Comment: @Scott According to Adobe, you can now have ["1 to 1000 artboards per document"](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/using-multiple-artboards.html) using Illustrator CC, depending on the size of the artboards.  Obviously this could still be problematic though if there isn't enough room to fit all 300 artboards in.

Comment: Ahh.. okay. Thanks @BillyKerr -- guess they updated that aspect.

Comment: @Scott - even so, I totally agree with you,  InDesign is designed for creating books. However, if the OP doesn't have access to InDesign, there's always Scribus which is free and Open source. Like InDesign, it has master pages which could be set up with guides. Then 299 additional pages could be inserted using the master page that has the guides set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe they don't have access to InDesign.  If you **have to** use Illustrator, I'd say  first create ALL the artboards you need (not completely necessary but might as well). Then go to board #1 and create the Guide(s) you want. After you're done, highlight the guides and "Cut", then use "Paste on All Artboards". That should add your margins to every page in exact same spot, then you can "paste in place" for any extra artboards created afterwards. If I'm understanding this correctly.

Forgot to add. Once you have your template created, look into saving as an .AIT file (Illustrator Template). Which you can then launch whenever you'd like!

Comment: Above answer works. Don't go through what I am going, use InDesign.